# Translate logic gates into logical expressions

Tags: logic-gates

I’m trying to understand the conversion of this particular logic gate to prove satisfiability.

[image]
I know the basics—AND, OR & NOT and also how the truth table works. I have this solution but I don’t understand this particular one is derived. Any explanation would help...

I want the logical expression not the evaluation of the logic table , for eample ((x1 OR x2)) AND (~(~x3)....

Comment: `x1` and `x2` both enter an OR gate, therefore the equation for that subcircuit is `x1 + x2`. Repeat until done.

Comment: If you know how to establish the truth table, you can use [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to find the expression easily. EDIT : it looks kinda cryptic from the wiki page but it's actually super simple

Comment: To add a little on what @FlorentEcochard was saying... K-Maps are the most simplified way of reducing a logic circuit such as this and it will give you a pretty simple output formula.